# Using URL parameters of one php file in another

Tags: php

I have a url with some parameters like `https://process.php?command=command3&arg=/home/items`
How do I get the values of command and arg in `https://process.php` and use them in process.php file

Comment: use $_GET , e.g. $command = $_GET['command'];

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But $command is present in `https://process.php?command=command3&arg=/home/items` but when I tried to do `echo $command` in process.php, it's not working

Comment: try this `print_r($_GET);` and check what it's print and also check your method e.g `GET,POST` it must be `GET` in your case

Comment: Can you show us some code where you already tried? Maybe this will help us to see where we need to direct you

Comment: It prints correctly when the url is `https://process.php?command=command3&arg=/home/items` but when I change the URL to `https://process.php` it prints nothing.
I am using `GET`